# Can't get it running 24/7 and triggered by a queue message

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

What ought to be quite simple has turned, as usual, into a game of trying to find docs and getting around teething problems.

I'm trying to get a simple webjob running, works fine locally but deploying it to azure via VS2013 appears to work but running create an error. This is apparently a known issue and i need to copy the exe to the root of the publish folders, so i've set my build to build into the root of the project. This *appears* to work.

The webjob is set on demand based on a message in a queue.

firstly on the webjob dashboard i get warnings about the connection strings but i have the strings in the app.config AND in the website portal too. So i don't know why this is coming up?

secondly once i publish i right click and run the webjob from VS2013, it starts and appears to work. But it runs and eventually times out with an error. The site is set to always on and it's a standard site, not running anything else.

So what am i supposed to do to keep the webjob running?

The job itself has an async signature because inside it's doing stuff with documentdb, so there's awaits and so on. Because it appears to be working i think all is well but that might be causing an issue?

The key is why does it run and then stop? What am i supposed to do to keep this listening for queue messages 24/7?

Answer (score 1):

If the job needs to run all the time it is not `on demand`. It must be `continuous`.

If that doesn't solve the problem, please share the job code.

Comment: The job itself i based on demand in the sense that it triggers when there is a message in the queue. In the site config it is set to always on. This is how i understand that a webjob based on message should be set up. I will try the other options if i can...

Comment: It seems from VS2013 i cannot choose the type of job, if i manually create it then yes i can create a continuous job but i'm not sure this is what i want. I want a job that is continuously waiting for a message in a queue, this appears to be an ondemand job? Otherwise i'm just wasting cycles restarting the task?

Comment: Sorry, that might be confusing. The `ondemand` and `continous` refers to the Azure WebJob type. The Azure WebJobs **SDK** is an SDK that runs inside a WebJob. `On demand` means that the code inside the webjob will execute at regular time intervals. The **SDK** has no notion of the job type and it actually independent of the WebJobs (can run outside). So, even though you want your code to be triggered on demand, you need a continuous job, otherwise the SDK cannot run all the time and therefore cannot listen for queue messages.